# NVMe SSD on mini ITX motherboard

Tags: ssd, cooling, nvme, heatsink, mini-itx

I'm looking to get an NVMe SSD on my computer, but I have a mini ITX build. However, everything I've read online strongly suggests that NVMe SSD's should use heatsinks to avoid excessive heat and performance degradation. My motherboard and case does not have room for a heatsink since the M.2 connector is on the backside of the board, right up against the back wall of the tower.

I also can't install the SSD into a PCIe slot since there is only one on my board, which is taken up by my graphics card.

I'm just looking for anyone else who has experience with using NVMe SSDs on a mini ITX build, or just without the heatsink in general. Have you run into any issues? Would you recommend it or not?

Thanks

Relevant specs
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-AB350N-Gaming WIFI
Case: NZXT Manta

Post-feedback edit: I'm going to use an M.2 extension cable (something like this [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08H89HWXN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08H89HWXN)) so I can place the SSD + heatsink on one of the empty storage drive slots.  That'll be a good place since it's right behind the intake fans.

Comment: The real problem is **degraded performance due to thermal throttling**. If it didn't have automatic thermal throttling an NVMe SSD that is installed without the heatsink would overheat and self-destruct.

Comment: Whether it’s Mini-ITX or not isn’t the deciding factor. The variety of case formats is too great to reduce it to this. The more important factors are airflow, airspace, how cramped the build is and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend installing an NVMe SSD without the heatsink. An NVMe SSD that is installed without the heatsink will overheat critically even during normal day-to-day use. When the NVMe SSD overheats the circuitry in the NVMe SSD will automatically throttle it which degrades the performance of the SSD and defeats the purpose of buying it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That's what I was worried about, but I think I expected this answer.  I wonder why this motherboard even has an M.2 connector then?  It's literally right up against the back plate.  Although, I wonder if I can use some kind of M.2 extender and attach the SSD with heatsink into my empty storage drive slots.